# cannot open connection of database in docker

Tags: mysql, database, docker

sql docker:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get -y install mysql-client mysql-server curl

RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf

ADD database.sql /var/db/database.sql

ENV user admin
ENV password admin
ENV url file:/var/db/database.sql
ENV right WRITE

ADD ./start-database.sh /usr/local/bin/start-database.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-database.sh
EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/start-database.sh"]
```

--------\------

startdatabase.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script starts the database server.
echo "Creating user $user for databases loaded from $url"

# Import database if provided via 'docker run --env url="http:/ex.org/db.sql"'
echo "Adding data into MySQL"
/usr/sbin/mysqld &
sleep 5
curl $url -o import.sql

# Fixing some phpmysqladmin export problems
sed -ri.bak 's/-- Database: (.*?)/CREATE DATABASE \1;\nUSE \1;/g' import.sql

# Fixing some mysqldump export problems (when run without --databases switch)
# This is not tested so far
# if grep -q "CREATE DATABASE" import.sql; then :; else sed -ri.bak 's/-- MySQL dump/CREATE DATABASE `database_1`;\nUSE `database_1`;\n-- MySQL dump/g' import.sql; fi

mysql --default-character-set=utf8 < import.sql
rm import.sql
mysqladmin shutdown
echo "finished"

# Now the provided user credentials are added
/usr/sbin/mysqld &
sleep 5
echo "Creating user"
echo "CREATE USER '$user' IDENTIFIED BY '$password'" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
echo "REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM '$user'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8
echo "GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO '$user'@'%'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8


#if [ "$right" = "WRITE" ]; then    
#echo "adding write access"
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES" | mysql --default-character-set=utf8

echo "finished"
#fi

# And we restart the server to go operational
mysqladmin shutdown
echo "Starting MySQL Server"
/usr/sbin/mysqld
```

When I run this docker file of sql it runs.
But when I link it to application using the command

```
$ docker run --link mysqldb -d abc // here abc is image name of application 
                                      & mysqldb is name of sql db image.
```

it terminates the server and shows cannot open the connection.
Even though I had provided privileges to it and also provided the ip addr of sql image to application image.
I have seen that my sql server is running properly and it connect to mysql client also.
Please proivide  a better solution**

Comment: We need to know what the abc container is trying to do and what logs its spitting out. Since its a custom application the container terminating is because the custom app process is terminating. Debugging that requires looking at logic for the custom app.

Comment: abc container running jboss server application   ERROR:  ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)
04:47:22,340 ERROR [CMTTxInterceptor] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
04:47:22,467 FATAL [AppInitManagerBean] Unable to initialize Application : javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Comment: :13:32,403 WARNING [JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
09:13:32,407 SEVERE [JDBCExceptionReporter] Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffac110003:126a:5667f089:11 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffac110003:126a:5667f089:11 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)
09:13:32,423 ERROR [CMTTxInterceptor] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connectio

Comment: 2:47,649 INFO  [LandingPageManagerBean] org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity: [com.digite.platform.organization.entity.Role#1]
05:52:47,671 INFO  [HornetQActivation] Attempting to reconnect org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQActivationSpec(ra=org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter@329b5cdd destination=queue/IformMDB_Queue destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15)
05:52:47,673 INFO  [HornetQActivation] awaiting topic/queue creation queue/IformMDB_Queue

Comment: < 06:46:15,020 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure